# How to return only top 5 records in Vue js nested loop

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, limit, nested-loops

I need to iterate over shoppingItem (items) inside shoppingOrder (orders). There are three orders. The first order has one item (itemid:1), second order has six items (itemid:2,3,4,5,6,7), third order has one item (itemid:8). I need to show only the top five items. i.e., 1,2,3,4,5 but the current code only limits the item in the second order, showing five items inside. The final output comes like 1,2,3,4,5,6,8

If first order has five items the loop should exit, if first order has one item and second order has six items, it has to show 1 in order 1 and 2,3,4,5 in order2 and exit before order3. But in my example, using `order.shoppingItem.slice(0,5)` only limits the items in the second order. It is not limiting the total items. How do I resolve this issue? I am using Vue JS version 2

**NestedLoop.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="order in shoppingOrder" :key="order.orderId">
      <div v-for="item in order.shoppingItem.slice(0,5)" :key="item.itemId">
        {{item.itemId}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "NestedLoop",
  data() {
    return {
      shoppingOrder: [
        {
          orderId: 1,
          orderDate: "7/30/2020",
          orderStatus: "Dispatched",
          shoppingItem: [
            {
              itemId: 1,
              itemName: "Pen",
              itemQuantity: "1",
              itemPrice: "10.00"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          orderId: 2,
          orderDate: "7/25/2020",
          orderStatus: "Ordered",
          shoppingItem: [
            {
              itemId: 2,
              itemName: "Notebook",
              itemQuantity: "2",
              itemPrice: "40.00"
            },
            {
              itemId: 3,
              itemName: "Scale",
              itemQuantity: "3",
              itemPrice: "100.00"
            },
            {
              itemId: 4,
              itemName: "Sharpener",
              itemQuantity: "1",
              itemPrice: "10.00"
            },
            {
              itemId: 5,
              itemName: "DocumentFolder",
              itemQuantity: "1",
              itemPrice: "10.00"
            },
            {
              itemId: 6,
              itemName: "PencilBox",
              itemQuantity: "5",
              itemPrice: "140.00"
            },
            {
              itemId: 7,
              itemName: "SketchBox",
              itemQuantity: "5",
              itemPrice: "10.00"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          orderId: 3,
          orderDate: "7/34/2020",
          orderStatus: "Dispatched",
          shoppingItem: [
            {
              itemId: 8,
              itemName: "Sketch",
              itemQuantity: "1",
              itemPrice: "10.00"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {}
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

**Result**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
8
```

**Expected only to return top 5 items like this (1 in order1 and then 2,3,4,5 in order2),**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love how succinct @Gaetan C's answer is, but `.flat` is a relatively new method that will require poly-filling for browsers if you are using Vue-cli 3. See this Github [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3834) for more details. If you run into any challenges, you may need to manually edit the poly-fill option of the babel preset.

For more compatibility among other browsers or if you are using vue cli 2 or below, I present this solution.

```js
computed: {
  firstFiveShoppingItems: {
     let initialShippingItem = [];
     for (const order of this.shoppingOrder) {
   
       if (initialShippingItem.length + order.shoppingItem.length >=5) {
         return [...initialShippingItem, ...order.shoppingItem].slice(0, 5);
       }

       initialShippingItem = [...initialShippingItem, ...order.shoppingItem]
     }
     return initialShippingItem;
  }
}
```

Then in your template, you add

```html
<div v-for="item in firstFiveShoppingItems" :key="item.itemId">
  {{item.itemId}}
</div>
```

As I said, it's not as elegant or succinct as @Gaetan C's answer but it will be more compatible among other browsers and you won't need to go through headaches with poly-fill configurations.

Another thing I like about my solution is that it doesn't iterate over all shopping item arrays like @Gaetan C's answer. It breaks when the result is obtained.

Comment: With her answer, there are two "for" loops. Are you sure it's better, performance wise? I doubt it, but I am glad you got your answer.

Comment: I am not able to edit the original comment. So I added it again.

I love all the three answers especially Gaetan's answer. From my experience, most methods not works in IE. Tony clearly explains the issue and I like his spread syntax approach. All three answers are perfect solutions. I tested all three solutions and all are working fine. It's tough to accept that only one is the best answer. Ann Kilzer answers with the basic nested loop concept and is easy to understand though we have to take the performance into consideration.

Comment: I will test your solution using the ESLint tool and will get back to you Tony.

Comment: I tested your code in the ESLint tool. It complains about the constant index is never used and the break is unreachable. The tool shows these issues as errors. Both issues have to be suppressed in ESLint to make it compile and it works now. It compiles perfectly without the ESLint tool. I need to suppress the error whenever I use the index. I think I have to change the ESLint settings. As you are using the ES6 syntax for-of loop, I am accepting your answer. This is one of my greatest learning experiences with all these three solutions.

Comment: Hi, @Abhikhya, I initially used the `index` in my answer but I forgot to take it out when it was no longer necessary. The break isn't necessary, either. My bad. Please don't suppress the errors. I will update the answer.

Comment: Hi, @Abhikhya, I have updated the code. It should work perfectly now with ESLint.

Comment: Hi Tony, Thank you for clarifying that. ESLint is happy now :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a computed property instead to get the 5 first shopping items:

```js
computed: {
  firstShoppingItems: {
    return this.shoppingOrder.map(x => x.shoppingItem).flat().slice(0, 5);
  }
}
```

Then you just need one `v-for` loop:

```html
<div v-for="item in firstShoppingItems" :key="item.itemId">
  {{item.itemId}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend taking advantage of Vue's [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) to make a list limited to five items. Currently your code is only slicing the inner list to five items.

```js
computed: {
    topFive() {
      const limit = 5;
      let count = 0;
      let res = []
      for (let i = 0; i < this.shoppingOrder.length && count < limit; i += 1) {
        let order = this.shoppingOrder[i];
        for (let j = 0; j < order.shoppingItem.length && count < limit; j += 1) {
          let item = order.shoppingItem[j];
          res.push(item);
          count++;
        }
      }
      return res;
    }
```

Once you have a computed property, you can call it from the template like so:

```html
<div v-for="item in topFive" :key="item.itemId">{{item.itemId}}</div>
```